# Label End-of-line Hyphenation Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

[image]

There is a label in the photo shown and it says "hello Hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia hello" inside.
What I want to do is to separate the part of the word that does not fit.

Example:

[image]

Label's existing features are as follows:

[image]

Comment: `wordWrap` comes in picture only if the string contains white space ` ` character, otherwise, if you want to break the string, you need to handle it manually.

Comment: Hyphenation is complicated and language-specific. To do it properly, you will need to use an external library, like [pyphen](https://pypi.org/project/pyphen/).